# How to throw exception if input params is invalid in Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates, configuration

Is there any way to **throw exception** if template input params are invalid? In django old version, we can do it like code below. But how about the latest django version? 
There is an option to set string_if_invalid = 'string' but the only reason we need to throw exception for this is that we obviously do not expect mail server to send trash emails to customers.

Thanks.

```
# settings.py in old versions
class InvalidVarException(object):
    def __mod__(self, missing):
        try:
            missing_str=unicode(missing)
        except:
            missing_str='Failed to create string representation'
        raise Exception('Unknown template variable %r %s' % (missing, missing_str))
    def __contains__(self, search):
        if search=='%s':
            return True
        return False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = InvalidVarException()
```

Answer (score 2):

## In Django<=1.9

```py
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = 'DEBUG WARNING: undefined template variable [%s] not found'
```

in your settings.py.

## In Django>=1.10

```py
string_if_invalid = 'DEBUG WARNING: undefined template variable [%s] not found'
```

[Also check this link about invalid template variables](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables)

[And this link about django backend template engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django)

Comment: It's ok, please if you find the solution post it here

Answer (score 0):

In pytest you can use `FAIL_INVALID_TEMPLATE_VARS`

See Docs: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#fail-on-template-vars-fail-for-invalid-variables-in-templates